# @EntityScan doesn't scan

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring boot application with Integration and Spring Data JPA. The configuration is as follows:

Application.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

IntegrationConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {
    private static final String FILE_PATTERN = "*.XML";

    @Value("${spring.integration.input-directory}")
    private String inputDirectory;
    @Value("${spring.integration.output-directory}")
    private String outputDirectory;
    @Value("${spring.integration.threads}")
    private int threadsCount;
    @Resource
    private ActualStatusRepository actualStatusRepository;

    //. . . removed file splitter and channels

    @Bean(name = "fiasEntityRouter")
    @Router(inputChannel = "afterSplitChannel")
    AbstractMappingMessageRouter fiasEntityRouter() {
        Map<String, String> routingMap = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
                .put("ru.ecoteck.entity.ActualStatus", "actualStatusChannel")
                .build();
        PayloadTypeRouter router = new PayloadTypeRouter();
        router.setChannelMappings(routingMap);
        router.setDefaultOutputChannel(logChannel());
        return router;
    }

    @Bean(name = "actualStatusChannel")
    public MessageChannel actualStatusChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "actualStatusHandler")
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "actualStatusChannel")
    public MessageHandler actualStatusHandler() {
        return new ActualStatusHandler(actualStatusRepository);
    }
}
```

So, the application starts read XML files, splits them into pieces, deserialize (by XStream) and then the object saves, I get an error that table `actual_statuses` doesn't exist. But in my `@Entity` annotated class I using a table with name `ActualStatuses`

```
@XStreamAlias("ActualStatus")
@Entity
@Table(name = "ActualStatuses")
public class ActualStatus {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("ACTSTATID")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACTSTATID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    // . . .
}
```

`ActualStatusHandler` is just calling `repository.save(message.getPayload)` but with a couple of protection code. Seems like the problem only with searching `@Entity` classes.
Spring boot version is 2.1.5.RELEASE.
I have tried explicit annotation `@EntityScan("my.package.entity")`, but with no effect. I don't use any custom database layer configuration. Just `application.properties`

```
#database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fias
spring.datasource.username=fias
spring.datasource.password=fias
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
# for debug
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

What's going wrong?
Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: can you add this property: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy` and try again

Comment: Is the table listed under public schema or any specific? Because the error says about Table Not exist that might hint to cross check the table name in db. Instead of object invalid which hints towards naming strategy.

Comment: @Rizwan All tables was created in `public` postgreSQL scheme.

Comment: @Patrick Configuration with  `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy` takes no effect. Moreother, this parameter marked as deprecated.

Comment: Hm. After parameter `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` has been added, The records in table was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

So, parameter

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

did the trick and now application works as expected. Thanks to **Patrick** for pointing me right direction to dig.